# How to add properties to a Form on a group, and show in Properties Windows and be editable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, properties

I have this class:

```
public class MyProps
{
    public MyProps()
    {

    }

    protected string myVar;
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return myVar; }
        set { myVar = value; }
    }

    protected int myOtherVar;
    public int MyOtherProperty
    {
        get { return myOtherVar; }
        set { myOtherVar = value; }
    }
}
```

That I want to add to my Form, so when I inherit from it I will be able to fill the properties in the MyPropsX property.

I have this code in my form:

```
    protected  MyProps propsX = new MyProps();

    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
    public  MyProps MyPropsX
    {
        get
        {
            return propsX;
        }
        set
        {
            propsX = value;
        }
    }
```

Now, the properties MyProperty and MyOtherProperty are nicely shown in the Properties Window, and I can set their values directly there.

But when I close my form and I open it again, all my changes are lost, the properties being reset to show zero and an empty string.

What am I missing?
Should I inherit my MyProps class from certain special class or interfase?
Or some special attribute?

Comment: When you close and re-open your form, do you use the same instance that holds the `MyProps` property or do you create a new one?

Comment: I'm using a testing application that just have the parent form and the inherited form. So, yes, I keep opening the child form, and the values are lost. These does not happen when I put properties directly on a form, so why this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little bit much for a comment and maybe your solution, so i'm answering to your comment with an answer instead with another comment:

With `does not happen when I put properties directly on a form` you mean, you are using the designer to set some property of the form. These will be written into the MyForm.designer.cs file. When you go into the code of your class you'll find within the constructor a method `InitializeComponent()`. Set the cursor on it an press <kbd>F12</kbd>. Here you can see what the designer has written into all the properties. You should respect the comment above the mentioned method and not start to modify the code with the code editor unless you really have understand how and when the designer will read and write code here (which is another chapter i can explain if needed). Otherwise it will happen that trying to opening your form with the designer after the code change will lead to an error message or code loss.

If you like to set some default value also, you should go back into the constructor and add the needed initialization code below the `InitializeComponent()` function and everything should work as expected.

#### Update

As you wrote in your comment you already know how the Designer interacts with the *.designer.cs file. So i really can't understand your concrete problem but maybe one of these articles can give you a more insight about how Microsoft wrote their components:

- [Make Your Components Really RAD with Visual Studio .NET Property Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302334.aspx)
- [Components in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171766.aspx)

Comment: Hi, yes I understand that property values are stored in the *.designer.cs file. I just want to my tiny class to "do that" as well. I suppose, my class should inherit from some advanced class, instead of Object in order to get that saving-property-values sort of automatically. But what is that?

Answer (score 0):

This is very normal, since each time you are closing the form and opening it again you are having a new instance from the form MyPropsX, so the best way would be to save your properties in any kind of a database (sql, access, textfiles,...)

Comment: But, when I add properties directly (without an additional class) they are saved without a problem. So why are these not being saved?